# HTTP callback once oozie job is complete

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie

Is there a way to make and external call once a worflow is completed in Oozie. Reading some documentation it seems like possible. (Oozie can make HTTP callback notifications on action start/end/failure events and workflow end/failure events.)

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html

But not sure how to do it and can it be an external api call on callback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Further down the document, [section 5](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a5_Oozie_Notifications)

What do you mean by external API call? It can only do an HTTP get - so if you configure a servlet endpoint or something similar to trigger that external API call when the URL is visited, then you should able to do pretty much anything you want.

It is also worth noting however that the docs say:

> Oozie will make a best effort to deliver the notifications, in case of failure it will retry the notification a pre-configured number of times at a pre-configured interval before giving up.

Comment: Thank you, section 5 does explain what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties you can add to your oozie job.properties. The variables $jobId , $status and $nodeName are replaced at runtime.

```
1. oozie.wf.workflow.notification.url=http://yourserver.com/some/path/$jobId/$status
```

This will give you a HTTP GET call at http://yourserver.com/some/path/ at job level for each status change for example

```
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:02] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/RUNNING HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:35] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/SUCCEEDED HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This one gives more detailed transition between your oozie job steps

```
2. oozie.wf.action.notification.url=http://yourserver.com/some/path/$jobId/$nodeName/$status
```

Sample output at server side :

```
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:02] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/:start:/T:ReadConfig HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:03] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/ReadConfig/S:RUNNING HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:09] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/ReadConfig/T:CheckStep HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:10] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop-table-import/S:RUNNING HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:10] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/CheckStep/T:sqoop-table-import HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:29] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/javaStatsReporting/S:RUNNING HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:29] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop-table-import/T:javaStatsReporting HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:35] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/end/T:null HTTP/1.1" 200 -
myhost.softlayer.com - - [19/Feb/2016 10:35:35] "GET /dbgen/lineitem2/0000050-151213000221460-oozie-oozi-W/javaStatsReporting/T:end HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```